# Cleaning Data: Multiple Misspelled Strings in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have over 100 strings that I want to change, for ex:
Scheduled Caste, Schdeduled Caste, Schedulded Caste need to be changed to SC.
I have been doing it like this: Haryana3$Category[Haryana3$Category%in% "Scheduled Caste"] <- "SC"
Is there anything I can do that's more efficient?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub`

```
Haryana3$Category <- gsub("Scheduled Caste", "SC", Haryana3$Category)
```

You can use `data.table` and try the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Haryana3)
Haryana3[, Catergory:= gsub("Scheduled Caste", "SC", Category)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the rule is combing all the first letter from each word. If that is true, here is one idea.

```
library(tidyverse)

Haryana3 <- Haryana3 %>%
  mutate(Category = strsplit(Category, split = " ")) %>%
  mutate(Category = map_chr(Category, ~paste0(str_sub(.x, start = 1L, end = 1L), collapse = "")))

Haryana3
#   ID Category
# 1  1       SC
# 2  2       SC
# 3  3       ST
# 4  4       ST
# 5  5       FC
```

**DATA**

```
Haryana3 <- read.table(text = "ID Category
1 'Scheduled Caste'
2 'Scheduled Caste'
3 'Scheduled Tribes'
4 'Scheduled Tribes'
5 'Forward Caste'", header = TRUE)
```